# How to remove/hide the "What's Hot" link from my Discussion board inside SharePoint online 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, development, discussion-board

I am working on SharePoint online 2013. and inside a Team site collection i added a new "Discussion Board" APP. now by default I got this views/filters:-

[image]

Now I am trying to remove the view/filter named "What's Hot" & "Featured", but could not find any link which allow me to remove/hide them. so can anyone advice on these please ?

Answer (score 2):

Put a Script Editor Webpart under your Discussion Webpart and put following CSS into it

```
<style>
.ms-comm-forumContainer .ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt[aria-label="What's hot"]{
     display:none;
}

.ms-comm-forumContainer li[text="Featured"]{
     display:none;
}
</style>
```

Replace Texts as you want

Comment: thanks for the reply. now i was thinking of providing this solution as the last option.. As i was searching for a more structured way of doing so (if possible). such as accessing a setting somewhere and then delete unwanted links .. is this possible?

Comment: I dont think so. Another Approach would be to switch into a different View, for example Flat View in List Settings.

Comment: now in my case i am showing the discussion board inside my site home page using App part, so the option to switch view is not avilable

Comment: another note for your appraoch , now as you are hard-coding the css classes names , so could the classes names be changed in the future (let say after a new feature or after an update is made to sharepoint online) which will cause the linkes to be shown again... so that why i am trying to find a more reliable appraoch  .. thanks